# how to generate fies dynamically in informatica cloud?

Tags: informatica-cloud

how to generate files dynamically in informatica cloud and how to call the windows batch script using informatica pre or post command?Please suggets?

Comment: SO is not a genie site. You should read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how to ask question properly.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic file, in Mapping, target transformation, select Target - Object Select button, check "Create New at Runtime" for target object

To call a batch script, in Mapping Configuration wizard, Schedule tab, under Advanced Options, add your batch file name in Preprocessing Commands or Post-processing Commands. Make sure to include full path.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Mapping target to create a file at runtime.
Target-> Select Object-> Create new file at runtime-> Use a Dynamic Filename

When you choose this option you get a range of options listed to generate your dynamic file.